# R&B Album 2016 poss. 2015

Tags: blues

I’m trying to find out what album is was/is…young African American singer, sounds a lot like Robert Cray, the album cover was black & white with him smoking on the cover…..anything? This album hits hard.
Could’ve been 2015 as well.

Also, it was indie. Not a big name. Thx!